# codigniter drop down list from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

//model

```
function shop_dropdown()
{
    $this->db->select('shop'); 
    $this->db->from('shop');
    //$this->db->where('category_online', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }
    return $data;

}
```

controller//

```
function shop_dropdown()
{
    $data = array();

    $this->load->model('shop_model');
    $shop['select_options'] =              $this->shop_model->shop_dropdown();
    $this->load->view('shop/product_view', $shop);


}
```

view//

```
<?php 
    echo form_dropdown('shop', $select_options);

?>
```

this is not not working.please help me creating a drop downlist from database.if you can write a new code.
thanks in advance

Comment: I am afraid you should learn how to ask questions properly if you expect any help. Telling something "it does not work" means really nothing and common answer to you request would be "so fix it".

Comment: i am new here.please fix this problem.i searched many times but i dont get the accurate code.

Comment: read FAQ on how to properly ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Modify like this

```
function shop_dropdown()
{
   $data = array();
   $this->load->model('shop_model');
   $shop = $this->shop_model->shop_dropdown();
   $this->load->view('shop/product_view', $shop);
}
```

and in your view

```
echo form_dropdown('shop', $shop->option);//option is an value taking form database
```

that's it.accept answer if it useful for you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have autoload form helper, if you didn't, you can't use the form_dropdown function unless you load it in the controller. I don't see you load form helper anywhere.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting 'shop' column in your model. 
I think your model should be like this

```
function shop_dropdown()
{
$this->db->select('id,name'); //column names you want to select, can be optional if you want to select all columns. 
$this->db->from('shop');   //table name, required
//$this->db->where('category_online', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{
 $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];  //make sure 'id' and 'name' ,columns are present in table
}
return $data;

}
```

And I hope you have edited application/config/databse.php